# How to get script to start over

Tags: powershell

I have this section of code that I need to loop through if the file is locked.
What I want to do is if the file is locked the script goes to sleep for 10 seconds then goes back to the if (test-Path) and runs through again until the file(s) are no longer locked. 
I'm just not understanding how to do this, any help is appreciated.

```
if (Test-Path -Path "$path\*") 
{  
 # Code for directory not empty

# enumerate the items array
foreach ($item in $items)
{
  # if the item is NOT a directory, then process it.
 if ($item.Attributes -ne "Directory")
 {
       $filePath = $path+$item.name          
 }
    else  
    {
    }
        function isFileLocked([string]$LockedPath) 
        {

        $oFile = New-Object System.IO.FileInfo $LockedPath
        # Make sure the path is good
        if ((Test-Path -LiteralPath $LockedPath) -eq $false)
        {       
          #If file is locked go to sleep for 2 minutes and check again, loop until the file is no longer locked.
          Start-Sleep -s 10
          # Go back and check directory again to see if more files have come in

          #return $false

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a while or do loop if you want it to go back to the if statement. If you want it to skip to the next item in the foreach loop you can use continue. help about_continue

Edit: example:

```
Do {
Start-Sleep -s 10
}
Until (Test-Path $LockedPath)
```

or

```
#Script block executes as long as condition value = True
While (! (Test-Path $Lockedpath) )
{Sleep 10}
```

The do until is easier logically to use, but the benefit of the second option is it tests the condition before executing the script block which in some cases (such as this one), it will be more efficient.

Comment: Good answer, but I would have liked to have seen an example given.

Comment: fair enough. added an example to help

Comment: I want to go back to "if (Test-Path -Path "$path\*")" if at all possible.

Comment: I showed you two examples of how to do it. The loop is doing the "if" test for you so adding another one would be redundant and pointless. Replace the whole if statement with one of my examples.